# Sending Bitcoins with Armory doesn't work

Tags: wallet, armory

I have a few Bitcoins that I manage with Armory. It shows the correct amount of money in my wallet under the correct address.

I now want to send the Bitcoins to somebody else. When I open my wallet and select the address with the Bitcoins and click on "Send Bitcoins," all that happens is my that my wallet window closes and I am back in Armory's main menu.

Is that a common problem? What should I do?

Comment: I'm trying to follow along with my own copy of Armory, but I'm not sure what you're doing. Do you mind posting a screenshot of the button that you're clicking on? You can black out sensitive information if you want.